# How to center text in a rectangle considering the height in canvas drawText?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, logic, android-canvas

I need some help.

I'm trying to center a text within a rectangle.

Currently, my logic reduces the font size to fit inside the rectangle. However, it reduces the font size so much that it doesn't break the line.

I need it to consider the width and reduce the font size if necessary.

I've tried some things but couldn't get it to work.

```kotlin
private fun DrawScope.drawBoundingBox(boundingBox: Rect, text: String, textMeasurer: TextMeasurer) {
    val defaultFont = 14.sp.value
    val fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.comic_sans))

    val currentWidth = textMeasurer.measure(text, TextStyle(fontFamily = fontFamily)).size.width
    val currentHeight = textMeasurer.measure(text, TextStyle(fontFamily = fontFamily)).size.height
    val desiredWidth = boundingBox.width()
    val desiredHeight = boundingBox.height()

    val widthScaleFactor = defaultFont * desiredWidth / currentWidth
    val heightScaleFactor = defaultFont * desiredHeight / currentHeight

    val newFontSize = min(widthScaleFactor, heightScaleFactor)

    val style = TextStyle(
        fontSize = newFontSize.sp,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        color = Color.Black,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        background = Color.White,
    )

    drawRoundRect(
        color = Color.White,
        topLeft = Offset(boundingBox.left.toFloat(), boundingBox.top.toFloat()),
        size = Size(boundingBox.width().toFloat() + 12f, boundingBox.height().toFloat() + 20f),
        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(2.dp.toPx(), 2.dp.toPx()),
    )

    drawText(
        textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
        style = style,
        topLeft = Offset(boundingBox.left.toFloat(), boundingBox.top.toFloat()),
        text = text.uppercase(),
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: What would to like the Text to do exactly? Do you want the text to take up most of the room it has and remain within the area of the bounding box provided? Or do you want it to remain on a single line and reduce it's size so it doesn't wrap the text to a new line?